# How to use grep to find value of html tag

Tags: html, grep, html-parsing

I want to analyze some aspects of my web page. For example I want to see the values of all **alt** tags. For the example I created simple html code which contain few **alt** tags. Let say that the tags inside the code are:

```
alt='Text-01'
alt='Text 02'
alt=''
alt='Some long text'
```

Then I tried command:

```
grep -o "alt='*'" my-page.html
```

The output is:

```
alt='
alt='
alt=''
alt='
```

I'm expecting to see the outputs like these ones:

```
Text-01
Text 02
empty line or alt=''
Some long text
```

or this one:

```
alt='Text-01'
alt='Text 02'
alt=''
alt='Some long text'
```

Can you help me to achieve that?

Comment: Try: `grep -o "alt='.*'" my-page.html`

Comment: The pattern you are supplying to grep, does not make sense. You are looking for `alt=`, followed by a sequence of one or more single-quotes.

Comment: `grep -oP "alt='\K[^']+" file` or `grep -oP "\salt='\K[^']+" file`

Comment: Trying to parse HTML by simple pattern matching is prone to errors.  Here are [some examples](http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html) of HTML that will run afoul of the grep solution.  The safest way to do this is to use an HTML parser in whatever language you're using.

Comment: Thank you!
That's work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know for certain, that the argument to *alt*  is between single quotes, you could do a

```
grep -o "alt='[^']*'" file
```

This searches for *alt=*, followed by a single quote, followed by an arbitrary number of non-single quotes, and finally from a terminating single quote.